# automatically adjust return type in java

Tags: java

In my project, I found that I'd like a method to create an Array of the same value. Don't worry, there's Array.fill(Array, value) for that, but I find myself often needing to array up a certain Object, so I tried to come up with a method for that:

```
private static Object[] unit(int len, Object val) {
    /*
     * creates an array of equal values
     */
    
    Object[] res = new Object[len];

    Arrays.fill(res, val);

    return res;
}
```

and then cast at the other end, but that gives me some weird errors about can't cast *weird class I have to use but can't modify*, so I'm trying to come up with a better solution.

I tried

```
private static Object[] unit(int len, Object val) {
    /*
     * creates an array of equal values
     */
    
    Object c=val.getClass();
    
    c[] res = new Object[len];

    Arrays.fill(res, val);

    return res;
}
```

but the compiler complains c isn't a legal argument. Is there any way I can avoid having to copypasta for like every object I want to use?

Comment: Why don't you just use a generic type like `<T>`? `static T[] unit<T>(int Len, T val)` ?

Comment: use generics, <T>

Comment: That's precisely why generics ("Parameterized Types") were introduced in Java 1.5: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas more like static <T> T[] unit (int len, T val)

Comment: Possibly related: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/529085)

Comment: @GeorgeWeekson yeah sorry that. ;) Hard to be accurate on a phone in a tiny input box.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Generics yet, TIL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics for this, as `HumanTarget` suggested, but you'll need [`Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,int)) to make a new `T[]`.

```java
<T> T[] unit(int len, T val) {
  T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(val.getClass(), len);
  Arrays.fill(res, val);
  return res;
}
```

You can also make multi-dimensional arrays by using the other [`newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,int...)) method, which will take multiple integers representing the dimensions of your array.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about Generics. I tried to also get rid of my double[] unit (int len, double val), but there it complained about being unable to convert from Double to double. Is there an elegant way to take care of that too, or am I stuck using all base types and then have one Generic for all Objects?

Comment: @RustyBucket `double`s are primitives and can't be treated as objects, so unfortunately, you'll probably need to make a special method for `double[]`.

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer, you think there's any chance that'll come in some new Java version?

Comment: @RustyBucket I doubt it. Perhaps Project Valhalla will bring them some day.

Comment: real bummer. Project Valhalla already sounds like something post-mortem, you sure that'll still be java by then?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want to use here is a [Generic Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

```
static <T> T[] unit(int len, T val) {
    /*
     * creates an array of equal values
     */
    T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(val.getClass(), len);
    Array.fill(res, val);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah fair enough, tried to write it from memory and considering I haven't written Java in ~ 6 years that was a BAD idea.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I also have the same method in double, is there a way to make it not complain "Can't convert from Double to double"?